# How Do My Website Urls have "Likes" when I haven't added a Like button to my Website?

Tags: facebook-like

In other words, what action from other people has triggered the URL of my website to get a "Like" without a Like button?  How can someone Like a url in Facebook without the button?

Comment: plugins, external scripts, blah blah blah. there's lots of ways to inject junk into a site without the webmaster's permission

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the comment. You are saying that someone has taken the time to add my website Url like button code to their website and people have Liked my url from other sites?  No one has injected anything into my site.

Comment: I don't really think this question is appropriate for StackOverFlow. It is not really a programming question.

Comment: @caesay -not sure what you mean.  the only way I know of that you can have likes on your page is through the facebook like button script. Scripting is programming. Is someone taking my script and using it on my site?  I'd appreciate any positive input if you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I really don't think this question belongs here at SOF. That being said, here are my two cents.

You can "Like" any URL. Button on it or not.

There is even a [chrome extension here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-like-button/jehaijobeonhempacbjelicepjkhoidi) that allows you to like any page from within the browser.

You can like a page simply by going to this URL even: `http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=[encoded url here]`

I think the real question is why you care if your website is being liked anyways? Why does it matter?

Comment: i want to be sure it's not spam..."real" likes are good for a few reasons. one of them is trust on a website.  thnx!